# Remote-SSH with Raspberry Pi not connecting

Tags: raspberry-pi, vscode-remote-ssh, vscode-server

I can connect no problem using a Terminal. When I attempt to connect to the Pi using the Remote-SSH VSCode extension, I get the following output:

```
[22:14:56.062] Log Level: 2
[22:14:56.160] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+dex.local", attempt 1
[22:14:56.161] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[22:14:56.161] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": false
[22:14:56.161] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[22:14:56.161] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[22:14:56.161] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[22:14:56.162] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[22:14:56.162] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[22:14:56.162] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[22:14:56.162] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[22:14:56.163] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[22:14:56.163] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[22:14:56.163] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[22:14:56.163] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[22:14:56.163] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[22:14:56.166] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[22:14:56.169] VS Code version: 1.84.1
[22:14:56.169] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.107.0
[22:14:56.169] darwin x64
[22:14:56.170] SSH Resolver called for host: dex.local
[22:14:56.170] Setting up SSH remote "dex.local"
[22:14:56.173] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-remote-ssh-cbfb80fb-install.lock
[22:14:56.174] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/Adam/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-cbfb80fb-2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f-0.107.0-tr/data.json
[22:14:56.175] Using commit id "2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f" and quality "stable" for server
[22:14:56.179] Install and start server if needed
[22:14:56.182] PATH: /usr/local/opt/ruby@3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/Adam/.composer/vendor/bin 
[22:14:56.182] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[22:14:56.187] > OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

[22:14:56.190] askpass server listening on /var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-8382067cb7aa71e2a6821a6f9d953c798451d9cd.sock
[22:14:56.190] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-6f004e77fe1e53e79428c10061e615dafb70d19e.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","49861","-o","ConnectTimeout=60","dex.local"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/Adam/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-cbfb80fb-2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f-0.107.0-tr/data.json"}
[22:14:56.191] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.n965XuOP0l/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-8382067cb7aa71e2a6821a6f9d953c798451d9cd.sock"}
[22:14:56.191] Spawned 1729
[22:14:56.320] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: "-v -T -D 49861 -o ConnectTimeout=60 dex.local"
[22:14:56.322] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=1733
[22:14:56.326] stderr> OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[22:14:56.673] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:ssf34qb6rMOe0iv3uHxKk6X1iq83H9pAMg/zVrX79Po
[22:14:56.818] Got askpass request: {"request":"pi@dex.local's password:"}
[22:14:56.819] Showing password prompt
[22:14:56.820] Listening for interwindow password on /var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-8509e108f3d17f2aebd84595b5f94cf85f094a20.sock
[22:14:56.820] Writing password prompt to globalState
[22:15:00.800] Got password response
[22:15:00.800] Interactor gave response: **********
[22:15:00.800] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[22:15:00.983] stderr> Authenticated to dex.local ([fe80::24ed:fcf5:2552:49f2%en1]:22).
[22:15:01.085] > Linux dex 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l
> 
> The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
> the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
> individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.
> 
> Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
> permitted by applicable law.
[22:15:01.273] > ready: 979f26ca8ab4
[22:15:01.280] > Linux 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019
[22:15:01.280] Platform: linux
[22:15:01.284] > /bin/bash
[22:15:01.284] Shell: bash
[22:15:01.284] Creating bash subshell inside "bash"
[22:15:01.292] > bash version:  4.4.12(1)-release
[22:15:01.333] > 979f26ca8ab4: running
[22:15:01.416] > Acquiring lock on /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/vscode-remote-lock.pi.2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f
[22:15:01.424] > Found existing installation at /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f...
[22:15:01.424] > Checking /home/pi/.vscode-server/.2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f.log and /home/pi/.vscode-server/.2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f.pid for a running server
[22:15:01.428] > Looking for server with pid: 1282
[22:15:01.476] > Running ssh connection command... /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/bin/code-server --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --accept-server-license-terms --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0 --telemetry-level all   &> "/home/pi/.vscode-server/.2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f.log" < /dev/null
[22:15:01.477] > printenv:
[22:15:01.478] >     LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
>     SSH_CONNECTION=fe80::142c:2fea:ced4:179d%wlan0 49862 fe80::24ed:fcf5:2552:49f2%wlan0 22
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>     INFINALITY_FT_CHROMEOS_STYLE_SHARPENING_STRENGTH=0
>     INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_INCREASE_GLYPH_HEIGHTS=true
>     INFINALITY_FT_CONTRAST=0
>     NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
>     INFINALITY_FT_STEM_FITTING_STRENGTH=25
>     INFINALITY_FT_GLOBAL_EMBOLDEN_X_VALUE=0
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=c8
>     USER=pi
>     INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_SNAP_STEM_HEIGHT=100
>     INFINALITY_FT_GRAYSCALE_FILTER_STRENGTH=0
>     INFINALITY_FT_GAMMA_CORRECTION=0 100
>     PWD=/home/pi
>     HOME=/home/pi
>     TEXTDOMAIN=Linux-PAM
>     SSH_CLIENT=fe80::142c:2fea:ced4:179d%wlan0 49862 22
>     INFINALITY_FT_WINDOWS_STYLE_SHARPENING_STRENGTH=10
>     INFINALITY_FT_BRIGHTNESS=0
>     MAIL=/var/mail/pi
>     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     INFINALITY_FT_USE_VARIOUS_TWEAKS=true
>     SHLVL=2
>     LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
>     INFINALITY_FT_BOLD_EMBOLDEN_Y_VALUE=0
>     INFINALITY_FT_GLOBAL_EMBOLDEN_Y_VALUE=0
>     INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_HORIZONTAL_STEM_DARKEN_STRENGTH=10
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/home/pi/.vscode-server
>     LOGNAME=pi
>     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
>     INFINALITY_FT_FILTER_PARAMS=11 22 38 22 11
>     INFINALITY_FT_STEM_SNAPPING_SLIDING_SCALE=40
>     INFINALITY_FT_USE_KNOWN_SETTINGS_ON_SELECTED_FONTS=true
>     INFINALITY_FT_STEM_ALIGNMENT_STRENGTH=25
>     INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_VERTICAL_STEM_DARKEN_STRENGTH=25
>     INFINALITY_FT_BOLD_EMBOLDEN_X_VALUE=0
>     INFINALITY_FT_FRINGE_FILTER_STRENGTH=0
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[22:15:01.496] > Removing old logfile at /home/pi/.vscode-server/.2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f.log
[22:15:01.500] > Spawned remote server: 3103
[22:15:01.512] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.562] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.601] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.648] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.699] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.758] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.813] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.864] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.919] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:01.973] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.027] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.083] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.133] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.188] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.243] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.297] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.353] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.407] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.462] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.514] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.576] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.623] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.681] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.737] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.791] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.846] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.901] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:02.956] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.011] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.066] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.118] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.177] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.228] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.283] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.338] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.395] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.446] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.501] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.556] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.609] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.664] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.718] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.774] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.828] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.883] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.937] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:03.992] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.043] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.100] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.155] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.209] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.265] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.319] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.374] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.423] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.482] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.536] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.592] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.647] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.702] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.753] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.811] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.866] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.923] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:04.973] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.034] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.083] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.142] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.196] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.250] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.304] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.361] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.416] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.469] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.522] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.574] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.630] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.685] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.739] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.794] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.855] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.904] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:05.956] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.008] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.062] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.115] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.171] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.226] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.282] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.336] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.392] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.446] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.502] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.555] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.608] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.663] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.717] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.775] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.827] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.882] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.938] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:06.992] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.047] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.102] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.157] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.212] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.266] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.336] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.371] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.429] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.511] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.535] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.595] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.643] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.701] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.756] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.811] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.881] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.932] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:07.983] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.032] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.092] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.144] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.200] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.254] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.311] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.364] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.419] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.474] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.528] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.583] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.638] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.693] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.747] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.802] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.854] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.908] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:08.963] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.018] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.073] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.130] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.182] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.237] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.292] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.347] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.403] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.457] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.518] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.564] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.619] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.672] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.726] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.782] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.836] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.891] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:09.949] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.002] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.057] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.111] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.166] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.222] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.281] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.326] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.384] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.438] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.491] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.546] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.601] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.658] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.712] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.773] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.833] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.871] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.929] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:10.984] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.039] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.095] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.146] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.201] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.257] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.312] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.366] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.423] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.477] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.532] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.589] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.639] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.695] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.750] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.803] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.856] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.910] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:11.964] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.015] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.073] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.128] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.183] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.238] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.293] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.348] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.402] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.455] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.509] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.559] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.614] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.669] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.723] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.778] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.833] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.887] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.943] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:12.997] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.052] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.106] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.161] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.213] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.269] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.325] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.378] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.435] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.488] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.542] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.597] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.652] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.707] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:13.760] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.030] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.031] > Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.037] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.182] > Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.193] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.289] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.303] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.428] > Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.468] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.523] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.578] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.634] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.690] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.746] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.802] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.857] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.904] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:14.964] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.021] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.073] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.128] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.183] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.237] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.293] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.347] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.402] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.457] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.512] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.568] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.628] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.677] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.732] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.787] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.844] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.897] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:15.953] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:16.004] > Waiting for server log...
[22:15:16.060] >  
> *
[22:15:16.061] > * Visual Studio Code Server
> *
> * By using the software, you agree to
> * the Visual Studio Code Server License Terms (https://aka.ms/vscode-server-license) and
> * the Microsoft Privacy Statement (https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-US/privacystatement).
> *
>  
[22:15:16.102] > Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /home/pi/.vscode-server/.2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f.log >>>
[22:15:16.105] > /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/node: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/node)
> /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/node: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/node)
[22:15:16.105] > <<< End of server log
[22:15:16.106] > 979f26ca8ab4: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==raspbian==
> arch==armv7l==
> vscodeArch==armhf==
[22:15:16.108] > bitness==32==
> tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==14568==
> 979f26ca8ab4: end
[22:15:16.109] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==raspbian==
arch==armv7l==
vscodeArch==armhf==bitness==32==
tmpDir==/run/user/1000==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==14568==

[22:15:16.109] Terminating local server
[22:15:16.111] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at g.ServerInstallError (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:642224)
    at d (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:635611)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:637881)
    at e (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:699953)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:721822
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:725481)
    at async /Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:696658
    at async C (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:694709)
    at async t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:696198)
    at async I (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:719045)
    at async t.resolve (/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:722852)
    at async /Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/extension.js:2:906656
[22:15:16.114] Local server exit: 15
[22:15:16.118] ------




[22:15:16.967] Opening exec server for ssh-remote+dex.local
[22:15:17.010] Initizing new exec server for ssh-remote+dex.local
[22:15:17.033] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-remote-ssh-cbfb80fb-install.lock
[22:15:17.039] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/Adam/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-cbfb80fb-2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f-0.107.0-es/data.json
[22:15:17.041] Using commit id "2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f" and quality "stable" for server
[22:15:17.043] Install and start server if needed
[22:15:17.048] askpass server listening on /var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-c8d75c994ded8ca7da54ba84e58fbfbdf9c33bf3.sock
[22:15:17.049] Spawning local server with {"serverId":2,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-13e332fb3289a6708b106104453dc8b032c023ef.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","49872","-o","ConnectTimeout=60","dex.local"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/Adam/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-cbfb80fb-2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f-0.107.0-es/data.json"}
[22:15:17.049] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.n965XuOP0l/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"--ms-enable-electron-run-as-node","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/Adam/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.107.0/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-c8d75c994ded8ca7da54ba84e58fbfbdf9c33bf3.sock"}
[22:15:17.051] Spawned 1790
[22:15:17.204] > local-server-2> Running ssh connection command: "-v -T -D 49872 -o ConnectTimeout=60 dex.local"
[22:15:17.206] > local-server-2> Spawned ssh, pid=1794
[22:15:17.210] stderr> OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[22:15:17.382] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:ssf34qb6rMOe0iv3uHxKk6X1iq83H9pAMg/zVrX79Po
[22:15:17.525] Got askpass request: {"request":"pi@dex.local's password:"}
[22:15:17.525] Showing password prompt
[22:15:17.526] Listening for interwindow password on /var/folders/vm/31g47k_s483dvnhl6ggt91qh0000gq/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-5d77b2629ad943c27a2b9658419b4a5ccd2fc3a5.sock
[22:15:17.526] Writing password prompt to globalState
[22:15:21.278] Password dialog canceled
[22:15:21.278] Interactor signaled cancel
[22:15:21.279] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[22:15:21.300] stderr> Permission denied, please try again.
[22:15:21.430] Got askpass request: {"request":"pi@dex.local's password:"}
[22:15:21.447] stderr> Permission denied, please try again.
[22:15:21.590] Got askpass request: {"request":"pi@dex.local's password:"}
[22:15:21.605] stderr> pi@dex.local: Permission denied (publickey,password).
[22:15:21.606] > local-server-2> ssh child died, shutting down
[22:15:21.611] Local server exit: 0
[22:15:21.611] Received install output: local-server-2> Running ssh connection command: "-v -T -D 49872 -o ConnectTimeout=60 dex.local"
local-server-2> Spawned ssh, pid=1794
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:ssf34qb6rMOe0iv3uHxKk6X1iq83H9pAMg/zVrX79Po
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
pi@dex.local: Permission denied (publickey,password).
local-server-2> ssh child died, shutting down

[22:15:21.612] Exec server for ssh-remote+dex.local failed: Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).
[22:15:21.612] Error opening exec server for ssh-remote+dex.local: Error: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

It seems to be hung up on `Waiting for server log`.

I have found many solutions to similar issues and they have not worked, here is a list of what I have tried:

1. I tried `rm -rf ~/.vscode-server` and then connect again - It did not work.
2. Also, I tried setting "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false which also did not help.
3. I've tried is to install an older version of the SSH extension in VSCode - it did not help.
4. I have tried adding `arm_64bit=0` to the `/boot/config.txt` file. Also did not work.

In the above output, just after the many `Waiting for server log`, there is an error about not being able to start VSCode Server and there is an error log in `/home/pi/.vscode-server/.2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f.log`:

```
/home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/node: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/node)
/home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/node: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /home/pi/.vscode-server/bin/2b35e1e6d88f1ce073683991d1eff5284a32690f/node)
```